# Check if std::wstring is null or empty

Tags: c++, null, wstring

How to check if an `std::wstring` is null or empty?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`wstring` is not a pointer, it cannot be null. You can check if it's empty (that is, is equivalent to `""`) either by direct comparison to the previous, or by:

```
str.empty(); // == (str.size() == 0)
```